# InStock QTY to be display after Login

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I am new to Magento, In my site i want to display the categories after login, but for some categories its displaying before login and some of the categories are unable to see the In Stock after login also. Can any one please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you mean to login into Magento admin or in front end?

Comment: I mean in front end login.

Comment: It may be the template/theme is made not show stock status

Comment: Not at all Because i have Three Links that is Shop By Manufacturer, Shop By Product Type & Shop by Vertical. In these three links for some of the products are displaying after login but some are NOT.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your question completely, but i think you want to show your categories only after the user is logged in?

You could only show the category menu after login using

```
<?php if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ): ?>
<-- Place the things you want the show here! -->
<?php endif ;?>
```

So if you use this in the topmenu (app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml) it would look like this

```
<?php if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ): ?>

<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php endif ;?>
```